# Probability of getting x heads n times when tossing 100 times

Tags: probability, chi-squared

I have 3 coins, and I flip them all together and count the number of heads I get. I repeat this 100 times and write down how many times I get 0 heads, ..., 3 heads.

I want to prove that based on my results the coins are biased. For that I want to use the Chi-Square Test, but I need to write my null hypothesis and I don't know how.

From what I understand, the null hypothesis would be that the coins are unbiased. And then I could write something like this:

- Every time I toss the coins I have $2^3$ possible outcomes
- So the probability of getting $x$ heads on a toss is $P'(x) = 
     \begin{pmatrix}
      3 \\
      x 
      \end{pmatrix}/2^3$
- Then if I do this 100 times, the probability of getting x heads, n times could be $P(n,x) = 
     \begin{pmatrix}
      100 \\
      n 
      \end{pmatrix}P'(x)^nP'(x)^{100-n}$

But I'm not sure if $P(n,x)$ is correct, is it?

If the formula was correct then I could use it to calculate the expected value and perform the Chi-Test.

Comment: $H_0$ claims that the coins are unbiased, hence the probability for zero or three heads is $1/8$ and for one or two heads $3/8$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe thanks for reasuring that that should be the claim. I tried to get to a formula based on that but I'm not sure if it makes sense

Comment: Then show your efforts, please.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment ...

If the coin was unbiased, we expect for the number of heads
$$\begin{matrix}
\text{number of heads}&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
\text{expected numbers}& 12.5 & 37.5 & 37.5 & 12.5
\end{matrix}
$$
Now, e.g., if the actual outcome was
$$\begin{matrix}
\text{number of heads}&0&1&2&3\\
\hline
\text{observed numbers}& 10 & 30 & 40 & 20
\end{matrix}
$$
calculate the test statistic
$${\chi^2}^\ast=\biggl(\sum\frac{(\text{observed number})^2}{\text{expected number}}\biggr)- n$$
and compare it with the critical value $\chi^2_{1-\alpha,n-1}$.